# Table content getting cutoff when converted from HTML page into MS Word 2003

Tags: html, css, ms-word, html-table

Table content is getting cut off on the right side of the page when converted from HTML page into MS Word 2003. Below given is a sample html (where placeholder $CLOB_DATA will be replaced by large CLOB data):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table width="80%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td> Details: </td>
                <td> $CLOB_DATA </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of the test word document(converted from above HTML code) is given below:

[image]

Please help me to fit the text to the page. I have given fixed width, word-break style to table and td tags, but its not working in word document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a fix for the issue. Use w:DontGrowAutofit (word XML element) in html header part.

```
<html xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word">
<head>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <xml>
        <w:WordDocument>
            <w:Compatibility>
                <w:DontGrowAutofit/>
            </w:Compatibility>
        </w:WordDocument>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try `word-break: break-word;`

```
body, table.body, td, th {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

this should fixed the problem

Comment: I have tried this. However its not working in word doc.